# g++ error message "use 'this->equal' instead?"

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I am trying to use stlplus ntree class and have written a program using it, and I have no problem compiling it in a Windows environment. I tried to port it into Ubuntu, but have errors.

stlplus ntree class uses template. Here is an example of my code

```
ntree<rule_node_struct> t;
ntree<rule_node_struct>::iterator cur_it;
if (cur_it == t.root())
{
// do something
}
```

When I compiled using g++, I get the following error message

> In instantiation of ‘bool stlplus::ntree_iterator::operator==(const this_iterator&) const [with T = rule_node_struct; TRef = rule_node_struct&; TPtr = rule_node_struct*; stlplus::ntree_iterator::this_iterator = stlplus::ntree_iterator]’:
>       /usr/lib/stlplus3-03-08/containers/ntree.tpp:133:19: error: ‘equal’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
>       /usr/lib/stlplus3-03-08/containers/ntree.tpp:133:19: note: declarations in dependent base ‘stlplus::safe_iterator, stlplus::ntree_node >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
>       /usr/lib/stlplus3-03-08/containers/ntree.tpp:133:19: note: use ‘this->equal’ instead

Why does g++ has this error while Windows Visual Studio does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a bug in the `ntree` class, as G++ does proper two-phase lookup of symbols, while VC seems to accept the broken code. Note that earlier versions of G++ also accepted this kind of code (AFAIK) and therefore it only got fixed in the latest version in the repository. Although that version is from 2010. It seems to me that it never made it into any release, so use the HEAD version or ask them to do a release.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have obtained the fixed code in the repository